# Jetty multiple acceptors blocked waiting to lock and object locked by other acceptor

Tags: java, multithreading, jetty

I'm facing an issue where the application hangs and possibly is due to blocked Jetty threads, but i'm not 100% sure in how to interpret the thread dump, if is normal what is observed and how does the jetty acceptors lifecycle is.

This is a particular part of the thread dump i'm observing:

```
"qtp1291915867-82 Acceptor0 SelectChannelConnector@0.0.0.0:3581 STARTING" prio=5 tid=0x52 state=BLOCKED
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.accept(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:281)
      - waiting to lock java.lang.Object@71918ba2 [owned by "qtp1291915867-84 Acceptor2 SelectChannelConnector@0.0.0.0:3581 STARTING" tid=0x54]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.nio.SelectChannelConnector.accept(SelectChannelConnector.java:97)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractConnector$Acceptor.run(AbstractConnector.java:833)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:598)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:533)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:804)

"qtp1291915867-83 Acceptor1 SelectChannelConnector@0.0.0.0:3581 STARTING" prio=5 tid=0x53 state=BLOCKED
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.accept(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:281)
      - waiting to lock java.lang.Object@71918ba2 [owned by "qtp1291915867-84 Acceptor2 SelectChannelConnector@0.0.0.0:3581 STARTING" tid=0x54]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.nio.SelectChannelConnector.accept(SelectChannelConnector.java:97)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractConnector$Acceptor.run(AbstractConnector.java:833)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:598)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:533)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:804)

"qtp1291915867-84 Acceptor2 SelectChannelConnector@0.0.0.0:3581 STARTING" prio=5 tid=0x54 state=RUNNABLE (running in native)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.accept0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.accept(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:305)
      - locked java.lang.Object@71918ba2
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.nio.SelectChannelConnector.accept(SelectChannelConnector.java:97)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractConnector$Acceptor.run(AbstractConnector.java:833)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:598)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:533)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:804)

"qtp1291915867-85 Acceptor3 SelectChannelConnector@0.0.0.0:3581 STARTING" prio=5 tid=0x55 state=BLOCKED
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.accept(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:281)
      - waiting to lock java.lang.Object@71918ba2 [owned by "qtp1291915867-84 Acceptor2 SelectChannelConnector@0.0.0.0:3581 STARTING" tid=0x54]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.nio.SelectChannelConnector.accept(SelectChannelConnector.java:97)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractConnector$Acceptor.run(AbstractConnector.java:833)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:598)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:533)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:804)
```

AFAIK, the amount of acceptors should be between 1 and # of CPU's, so i'm assuming this is running in a 4 Core CPU, the question is, from jetty perspective, is it normal that other acceptors be blocked waiting to other acceptors resource? if so, what this resource could be?

I'm not very fond on Jetty so i don't really know if this is normal and they are just waiting for they turn to attend incoming connections, if so, then the issue is in different place but i would like to discard the jetty part.

Btw, the jetty version is 7.5.4

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: [Jetty 7 and Jetty 8 are EOL (End of Life)](https://dev.eclipse.org/mhonarc/lists/jetty-announce/msg00069.html), consider upgrading.

Comment: Thanks @JoakimErdfelt unfortunately that might not be possible in short term so for now i would need to deal with this situation.

Comment: Nothing about the stacktraces indicates a problem (from one data point).  Try accessing a static resource when you experience this perceived "hang".  If jetty responds, even with a 404, then its not jetty causing problems, its your web application.

Comment: Since Jetty 7.5.4, there have been over 180 stable releases of Jetty (2 major servlet api revisions, and 7 major version releases).